# Namespace 'VisualStudio' does not exist, VS 2015

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2015

I installed Visual Studio 2015 and now I'm getting the following exception on all my unit test classes

```
The type or namespace 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the Namespace 'Microsoft'
```

[image]

Is anyone else experiencing this problem?

Here is the reference

[image]

Comment: Is the test project referencing [Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.testclassattribute(v=vs.140).aspx) ?

Comment: @StuartLC Yes it is, I included an image of the references

Comment: Can you put your project somewhere to be examined by others? Are you using `Visual Studio` final or RC/Beta versions? What edition are you using?

Comment: @afsharm, unfortunately there is a lot of intellectual property involved, so I don't think my company would be to happy with me if I give access to 3rd parties to examine the project. To answer your second question, I'm using Visual Studio final version (Professional)

Comment: @user65439 So try test solve the problem as isolated as possible. That means create a simple empty project and see if `Microsoft Unit Testing` works properly. If worked then try adding other portions of the project. This way you can better detect the real cause root.

Comment: @afsharm, will do, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to give some background on the problem, the solution that I experienced problems with was a Visual Studio 2013 solution that was migrated to Visual studio 2015. When I looked at the location of the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll` it was pointing to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
```

I then created a new solution from Visual Studio 2015 containing only a unit test and had a look at the location of the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll` reference, which was pointing to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
```

I removed the references to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll` from all my Visual Studio 2015 projects and pointed them to the dll contained in

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
```

This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it would go back to 11.0 for you, but my path was 14.0

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll
```

Even just changing

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

to

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

works fine.  If you manually browse it the dll, it may decide to add a crazy hint path.

To be safe, the best way is probably to update the reference to

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
</Reference>
```

So that anyone using 2013 does not get the problem.